# Can't start mongodb on AWS instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have worked on mongodb database. I have installed this in my server & worked on this. But currently I am facing a problem. My mongodb database is not responding. When I am giving this command :  mongo

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: test
2015-07-02T06:22:11.363+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-07-02T06:22:11.364+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

I have already delete the lock file, then repair mongodb then restart mongodb. But cant solve my problem.

Here is my `mongodb.log` file:

```
2015-07-02T06:30:48.789+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5551 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ip-172-31-5-213
2015-07-02T06:30:48.789+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
2015-07-02T06:30:48.789+0000 [initandlisten] git version: 5901dbfb49d16eaef6f2c2c50fba534d23ac7f6c
2015-07-02T06:30:48.789+0000 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build18.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-07-02T06:30:48.789+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-07-02T06:30:48.789+0000 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] 
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] 
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2015-07-02T06:30:48.801+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-07-02T06:30:48.801+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-07-02T06:30:48.801+0000 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-07-02T06:30:48.801+0000 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2015-07-02T06:30:48.801+0000 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2015-07-02T06:30:48.802+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-07-02T06:30:48.803+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: Please, add content of your mongodb log file. By default it's `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`.

Comment: I cant add this log file info here. Please check in mediafire : http://www.mediafire.com/view/7yzkq55cat5b6au/log.txt

Comment: Is this problem for space ?

Comment: 2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
2015-07-02T06:30:48.800+0000 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles

Comment: Try to run `mongod` first .

Comment: @NazmulHossainBilash added it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your `mongodb.log` file:

```
ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles
```

You don't have enough disk space to start your MongoDB service. MongoDB fails to allocate disk space for its [Journal Files](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/#journal-files).

I can see four possible solutions for your problem:

- Add more disk space (cleanup something, or use larger storage). If you're using AWS, you could [expand your EBS Storage Space keeping all existing data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html).
- Reduce journal size using [`--smallfiles` key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--smallfiles) or by setting [storage.mmapv1.smallFiles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.mmapv1.smallFiles) to `true`.
- [Disable Journaling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-journaling/#disable-journaling) using [`--nojournal` key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--nojournal) or by setting [storage.journal.enabled](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.journal.enabled) to `false` (**not recommended**).
- [Upgrade your MongoDB to `3.x`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/#upgrade-mongodb-to-3-0) and [change your storage engine to WiredTiger](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/#change-storage-engine-to-wiredtiger), it'll reduce your overall database size and free some disk space. But you'll need additional disk space for data migration.

Comment: Perfect solutions. 4th option would be better one.

Answer (score 0):

Error has been rised typically it was mongodb crash. 
Solution :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongod restart
sudo service mongod stop
sudo service mongod start
```